# Does `UserManager<TUser, TKey>` exist in .NET core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity

I used to develop ASP.NET sites using ASP NET Identity. Using it, I had this UserManager: `UserManager<TUser, TKey>`. That way, I could use `TKey` as `int` because my database tables used `int` identity fields. So, I could do things like this: `_userManager.FindByIdAsync(1);`. That instruction returned the user whose identity was 1.

With .NET Core, I could create my own `ApplicationUser` this way:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FirstLoggedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLoggedOn { get; set; }
}
```

So I am telling the system that the key field is an integer.

How can I do the same for `UserManager` so that I don't need to convert the identity to string in calls such this one: `_userManager.FindByIdAsync`?

The only `UserManager` I could find in .NET Core was: `UserManager<TUser> : IDisposable where TUser : class`

Regards
Jaime

Comment: You need to change the Guid to Int. This is for .Net but should give you an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

Comment: @GHDevOps It seems the question was not clear enough. Please tell me what was not clear so I can edit the question. I told in the question that my identity field already is `int`. In .NET Identity (as in your example) I can change the GUID to be an INT. I need to know how to achieve the same but in .NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could check the two documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn613290(v=vs.108)#inheritance-hierarchy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Inheritance hierarchy in .NET framework:

```
System.Object
  → Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TUser, TKey>
    → Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TUser>
```

Inheritance hierarchy in .NET 6:

```
Object →  UserManager<TUser> →  AspNetUserManager<TUser>
```

There is no `UserManager<TUser, TKey>` in .NET 6 anymore.

You could also press <kbd>F12</kbd> and then get into `UserManager<TUser>` class to check the method.

It just accepts arguments type of string and there no override methods in `AspNetUserManager<TUser>`

[image]

For default `IdentityUser` was defined as below:

[image]

Comment: Yes... I realized there is no other constructor anymore. I wonder why Microsoft took such a decision, since sometimes a table identity is not a GUID but an autoincrement field whose type is integer. Also, all IdentityUser methods have changed, both, method parameters and return values.